# Why no back button on DateElement picker?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

[This walkthrough for MT.D](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/User_Interface/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements_API_Walkthrough)  shows a back button on the UIDatePicker that appears when a DateElement is tapped. I'm in an iPad app, and using an MT.D DialogViewController *as a subview* in an overall UIView. When the date picker slides up I just get the black background with no way to dismiss the picker (no nav bar w/ back button). Same problem exists for the radio group picker. Is this because the dialog view controller is being used as a subview? Any ideas how I might get a nav bar up with a back button using the built-in picker logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the DialogViewController as a child element of a UINavigationController to get the back button. On iPad, you can embed the UINavigationController in a UIPopoverController.
Adding the view of a controller into the view of another controller is not considered good design on iOS and won't result in the behavior you expect.

Comment: What you say makes sense based on what I'm seeing. And I understand also about the option to embed it in a popover controller. But it seems limiting that you can't embed a DVC type view as a subview, since from the outside looking in its "like" a UITableView which can be embedded. But yeah the controller has all the fancy logic for dealing with the declarative-based view creation I'm sure. Thanks for the info!